# VTL: Add a new property to an maps inside an array (AWS Appsync, DynamoDB)

Tags: amazon-dynamodb, aws-cdk, aws-appsync, vtl

I'm new to VTL and AWS appsync and try to get my head around how things are working.

The maps that are representing Steps in a List should have the property `id` with a UUID before there are stored in DynamoDB. To accomplish this I tried to iterate over the array and access the put method on the map like in the example below.

```
{
  "version" : "2017-02-28",
  "operation" : "PutItem",
  "key": {
      "id" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId())
  },
  #set($input = $util.dynamodb.toMapValues($ctx.args.input))
  #set($input.createdAt = $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDB($util.time.nowISO8601()))

  #foreach($step in $input.steps)
    $step.put('id', $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId())))
  #end 

  "attributeValues": $util.toJson($input)
}
```

my second try:

```
#foreach($step in $input.steps)
    #set($step.id = $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()))
  #end
```

but still, for no reason, my maps do not have the property `id`.
Is there maybe the problem what the `foreach` loop is giving me just a copy of the map I try to modify and not the original object?

Thank you for your time!
Hopefully, my question will serve all newbies to VTL and appsync

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They do, it's just that the toMapValues utility method is returning you DynamoDB types.

So if "input.steps" is supposed to be a list what you're gonna get in there is an object like {"L": [ ... ]}

Try this:

```
#foreach($step in $input.steps.L)
    $step.put('id', $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId())))
  #end
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation what's a really good startingpoint! I had to make a small modification for calling the put method to omit some issues: `$!{step.put("id", $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($util.autoId()))}`

After running a new Mutation, appsync gives me a new error. Maybe you know the solution. `Unsupported value type 'id' in '$[attributeValues][steps][L][0]'`

Comment: Sure,  I can help you with the resolver. A few questions so that I'm able to understand: what are the arguments beind passed to the API? What's the resulting object that you want in DynamoDB? what should be the output of the API?

Comment: I fixed the issue. It was something on my side. Thank you for your Time!